# Namespace A - floder A / subfolder B- sub namespace B ?

Tags: php, namespaces

I am new with php namespaces and I encounter an issue. Here is a resume of my code :

In folder **controller**:

```
namespace controller;
require_once 'templates/Singleton.php';

class OrderConfirmationController extends Singleton {
    ...
}
```

In sub folder **controller/templates**:

```
// class out of any namespace
class Singleton {
    ...
}
```

I always have an error message even if I extends OrderConfirmationController with \Singleton.

I am not sure to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the namespace reference when you extent the singleton class. An easy way would be with a `use` statement at the top of your controller and and appropriate alias.

```
use \SingletonNamespace\Singleton as Singleton;
```

Or

```
class OrderConfirmationController extends NameSpace\Singleton {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue is that I cannot yet add Singleton in a specific namespace because that would be a lot of work for me to change all my classes. Singleton is out of any namespace and should be, if I understand well, in the Global namespace. But when I use backslash in `extends \Singleton`, there is an error.

Comment: Actually `spl_autoload_register` is called and seems to look for `controller\Singleton` class which has no existence because not in `controller` namespace; just in subfolder **templates**.from **controller** folder.